# Cannot replace colons with .replace() method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to replace every instance of a colon in a .txt file with double dashes - "--"

```
textof = []

with open("myfile.txt") as myfile:
    textof = myfile.readlines()

for line in textof:
    if ":" in line:
        for char in line:
            if char == ":":
                line = line.replace(":", "--")

print(textof[0])
```

the string print() returns is the same as it was in the original .txt - with colons, and no double dashes. not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: You are not changing the contents of textof. You should print (line) inside the loop instead.  Then save the contents of line into a new file.

Comment: Note, you don't need *either* the `for char in line` or the `if char == ":"`.

Comment: Don't need `if ":" in line:`, either

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're being misled. The replacement *is* happening, it's just not getting saved. When you do

```
line = line.replace(":", "--")
```

you're not changing the `line` from `textof` - instead, you're making an entirely new variable and changing the name `line` to point to that. To change the original, you'll need to do something like this:

```
for idx in range(len(textof)):
    textof[idx] = textof[idx].replace(":", "--")
```

which changes the list `textof` *directly*. Or you could be flashy and do it in a list comprehension, which is the idiomatic way of doing it - this doesn't modify the original list, it just creates a new one however you want it:

```
replacedLines = [line.replace(":", "--") for line in textof]
```

---

Note that you also want to write this to a file, and you'll  have to do that explicitly:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as myfile:
    myfile.writelines(replacedlines)
```

Comment: It's not really a new variable; it's the same name, but now it's referring to a different object.